# Conditional Formatting for rows

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

How do you drag the conditional formatting across the row? For example I have color red for not equal to and green for equal to, but how can you apply the conditional formatting across the row "Due" for the other dates?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2ayv.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your conditional formatting rules seem to be wrong.

That should do it:

1. Erase your current "Conditional formatting" rules.
2. Select the desired cells in row 10, starting from `F10`.
3. Click *Conditional formatting* / *New rule* / *Formula*.
4. Enter `=F$10=F$11`, click "format" and choose green fill color. Confirm with "OK" twice.
5. Repeat step 2 and 3.
6. Enter `=F$10<>F$11`, click "format" and choose red fill color. Confirm with "OK" twice.

**Note**:
The formula is always based on the active cell (the one you choose first in your selection, here `F10`).

Comment: It's is possible to drag this conditional formatting across the row? That's where I struggle; to apply the same conditional formatting from G10:J10. Thank you Qualia

Comment: Sure, but dragging is not necessary, if you select the the cells F10 to J10 in Step 2.

Answer (score 0):

Conditional Formatting > Manage Rules, select your relevant rule and edit the 'Applies to' range field to include the cells you want it to apply to.

Comment: It's not working, if you look at the picture I edited the 'Applies to' range field to include the cells but it's not returning correctly.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't view the picture due to a browser error here; you'll have to clarify the question. Is it that you want the entire row to be affected by a single cell's value?

Comment: No worries, I think I got it but it's a pain to do and copy paste formatting across the row.